# MongoDB group by ID and then by date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have a collection in my MongoDB database that stores durations for people who are in groups, it looks a like this:

```
[{
    "_id": "5c378eecd11e570240a9b0ac",
    "state": "DRAFT",
    "groupId": "5c378eebd11e570240a9ae49",
    "personId": "5c378eebd11e570240a9aee1",
    "date": "2019-01-07T00:00:00.000Z",
    "duration": 480,
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "5c378eecd11e570240a9b0bb",
    "state": "DRAFT",
    "groupId": "5c378eebd11e570240a9ae58",
    "personId": "5c378eebd11e570240a9aeac",
    "date": "2019-01-07T00:00:00.000Z",
    "duration": 480,
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "5c378eecd11e570240a9b0c5",
    "state": "DRAFT",
    "groupId": "5c378eebd11e570240a9ae3e",
    "personId": "5c378eebd11e570240a9aef6",
    "date": "2019-01-07T00:00:00.000Z",
    "duration": 480,
    "__v": 0
}]
```

I would like to be able to run an aggregate query which returns a collection of `personIds` and the `duration` grouped per day with the corresponding `groupId`, which would look like this:

```
[{
    "personId": "5c378eebd11e570240a9aee1",
    "time": [{
        "date": "2019-01-07T00:00:00.000Z",
        "entries": [{
            "groupId": "5c378eebd11e570240a9ae49",
            "duration": 480,
            "state": "DRAFT"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "personId": "5c378eebd11e570240a9aeac",
    "time": [{
        "date": "2019-01-07T00:00:00.000Z",
        "entries": [{
            "groupId": "5c378eebd11e570240a9ae58",
            "duration": 480,
            "state": "DRAFT"
        }]
    }]
}, {
    "personId": "5c378eebd11e570240a9aef6",
    "time": [{
        "date": "2019-01-07T00:00:00.000Z",
        "entries": [{
            "groupId": "5c378eebd11e570240a9ae3e",
            "duration": 480,
            "state": "DRAFT"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

So far, I have written the following aggregation (I'm using Mongoose, hence the syntax):

```
Time.aggregate()
    .match({ date: { $gte: new Date(start), $lte: new Date(end) } })
    .group({
      _id: '$personId',
      time: { $push: { date: '$date', duration: '$duration', state: '$state' } },
    })
    .project({ _id: false, personId: '$_id', time: '$time' })
```

Which returns the following:

```
[{
    "personId": "5c378eebd11e570240a9aed1",
    "time": [{
        "date": "2019-01-11T00:00:00.000Z",
        "duration": 480,
        "state": "DRAFT"
    }, {
        "date": "2019-01-11T00:00:00.000Z",
        "duration": 480,
        "state": "DRAFT"
    }
    // ...
}]
```

Hopefully you can see that the `duration`s are being grouped by `personId` but I've not been able to figure out how to apply another grouping to the `time` array as the `date`s are duplicated if a `personId` has more than one `duration` for a given date.

Is it possible to group by and ID, push to an array and then group the values in that array as an aggregation or will my application need to map/reduce the results instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest running two `$group` operations in a row:

```js
db.time.aggregate({
  // first, group all entries by personId and date
  $group: {
    _id: {
      personId: "$personId",
      date: "$date"
    },
    entries: {
      $push: {
        groupId: "$groupId",
        duration: "$duration",
        state: "$state"
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  // then, group previously aggregated entries by personId
  $group: {
    _id: "$_id.personId",
    time: {
      $push: {
        date: "$_id.date",
        entries: "$entries"
      }
    }
  }
}, {
  // finally, rename _id to personId
  $project: {
    _id: 0,
    personId: "$_id",
    time: "$time"
  }
})
```

In Mongoose it should be something like that:

```
Time.aggregate()
  .match({
    date: {
      $gte: new Date(start),
      $lte: new Date(end)
    }
  })
  .group({
    _id: {
      personId: '$personId',
      date: '$date'
    },
    entries: {
      $push: {
        groupId: '$groupId',
        duration: '$duration',
        state: '$state'
      }
    }
  })
  .group({
    _id: '$_id.personId',
    time: {
      $push: {
        date: '$_id.date',
        entries: '$entries'
      }
    }
  })
  .project({
    _id: false,
    personId: '$_id',
    time: '$time'
  })
```

Comment: This works great - thanks! Do you know if there's a way to sort the values in `entries` by the `groupId` property and then sort the values in `time` by `date`?

Comment: Managed to figure it out actually - I sort by `groupId` after the match, then I sort by `date` after the first group.

Comment: @edcs actually, you only need one `$sort` call. You could sort your data by both fields at the same time: `{ $sort: { date: 1, groupId: 1 } }`.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection("dummyCollection").aggregate(
[
    { 
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$personId", 
            "time" : {
                "$push" : {
                    "date" : "$date", 
                    "duration" : "$duration", 
                    "state" : "$state"
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$project" : {
            "_id" : false, 
            "personId" : "$_id", 
            "time" : "$time"
        }
    }, 
    { 
        "$unwind" : "$time"
    }, 
    { 
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : "$time.date", 
            "time" : {
                "$addToSet" : "$time"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

);

> Use $addToSet which returns an array of all unique values that results from applying an expression to each document in a group of documents that share the same group by key.